# How to route to a dynamic URL expressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create a login page, such that when the user successfully logs in the app goes to the URL `localhost:3000/:username`. So for instance when a person with username `john`logs in the app should go to `localhost:3000/john`. I read this page on express routing https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html but it does not seem to explain this. It only explains how to get the username from the URL but not the other way around (how to route to a different URL depending on the username). Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: After login, create the URL you want the browser to go to and use `res.redirect(url)` to tell the browser to go to that web page.  Then, create a route with a wildcard for the username.  But, I'd recommend against `/:username` because that matches ALL top level routes which means you create potential conflicts with any other top level routes like `/login` that your website wants to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redirection after the user login successfully.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// login page
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.send(`This is login page`);
});

// login verification
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  // verify user
  const user = getUserByEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password);

  // set session  
  // ...

  // redirect
  res.redirect(`/${user.username}`);
});

// private user page
app.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
  const username = req.params.username;
  res.send(`Hello ${username}`);
});
```

Comment: `app.get('/:username', ...)` is generally not recommended because it matches ALL top level routes, creating potential conflicts between usernames and any other top level routes your web site wishes to use such as `/about`, `/contact`, `/home`, etc... and can complicate future growth of the website.   `/user/:username` might be a better option.